# can we optimize below code using generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a Service class, which makes 2 different calls to another API which returns 2 different response objects.  For Simplicity let that be shown as below

```
public class Service {

    public AddResponseWrapper add(Request request)  {

        final AddResponseWrapper addResponseWrapper = new AddResponseWrapper();

        try {
            final AddResponse addResponse = addApi.add(request);
            addResponseWrapper.setAddResponse(addResponse);

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            addResponseWrapper.setErrorDetails(convert(e));
        }
        return addResponseWrapper;
    }

     public DeleteResponseWrapper delete(Request request)  {

     final DeleteResponseWrapper deleteResponseWrapper = new DeleteResponseWrapper();

        try {
            final DeleteResponse deleteResponse = deleteApi.delete(request);
            deleteResponseWrapper.setDeleteResponse(deleteResponse);

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            deleteResponseWrapper.setErrorDetails(convert(e));
        }
        return deleteResponseWrapper;
    }
}
```

Similarly, I have these 2 below POJOs created

```
public class AddResponseWrapper {

    private AddResponse addResponse;

    private ErrorDetails errorDetails;

    public AddResponse getAddResponse() {
        return addResponse;
    }

    public void setAddResponse(final AddResponse addResponse) {
        this.addResponse = addResponse;
    }

    public ErrorDetails getErrorDetails() {
        return errorDetails;
    }

    public void setErrorDetails(final ErrorDetails errorDetails) {
        this.errorDetails = errorDetails;
    }

}


public class DeleteResponseWrapper {
    
        private DeleteResponse deleteResponse;
    
        private ErrorDetails errorDetails;
    
        public DeleteResponse getDeleteResponse() {
            return deleteResponse;
        }
    
        public void setDeleteResponse(final DeleteResponse deleteResponse) {
            this.deleteResponse = deleteResponse;
        }
    
        public ErrorDetails getErrorDetails() {
            return errorDetails;
        }
    
        public void setErrorDetails(final ErrorDetails errorDetails) {
            this.errorDetails = errorDetails;
        }
    
    }
```

The AddResponseWrapper & DeleteResponseWrapper are classes that I have created, while the AddResponse and DeleteResponse classes are classes that I inherit from the API that I call.

Now if I make 2 more APi calls, for say Subtract & Multiply operations, I would have to create 2 more POJO classes SubtractResponseWrapper and MultiplyResponseWrapper.

I do not find this solution clean, what I would really like to have is a Generic class, that should be returned from each of these calls and I can avoid the use of multiple Pojo classes.

Comment: It's not a generics thing .. you have the clue in your words - they are operations...  So have an `OperationResponseWrapper` and `getOperationResponse` / `setOperationResponse` .. your AddResponse/DeleteResponse//multipleResponse/etc should all then implement an interface `OperationResponse` - with say a method `apply()` on it - which has the code that each of the Add/Delete/etcResponse classes implment differently.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but as I mentioned, AddResponse/DeleteResponse//multipleResponse/ classes  are derived classes from Swagger API client generator so I would not be able to edit those.

Comment: There's no Swagger mentioned in your question but sure if you can't change anything then your stuck.   You can definitely have a Wrapper<T>, however without some sort of heirarchy you are going to end up with Wrapper<Object>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - however without some sort of heirarchy in your response objects it's possibly going to be not much better than `ResponseWrapper<Object>`.

```
public class ResponseWrapper<T> {
    
        private T response;
    
        private ErrorDetails errorDetails;
    
        public T getResponse() {
            return response;
        }
    
        public void setResponse(final T response) {
            this.response = response;
        }
    
        public ErrorDetails getErrorDetails() {
            return errorDetails;
        }
    
        public void setErrorDetails(final ErrorDetails errorDetails) {
            this.errorDetails = errorDetails;
        }
    
    }
```

Then your service becomes -

```
public class Service {

    public ResponseWrapper<AddResponse> add(Request request)  {

        final ResponseWrapper<AddResponse> addResponseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper<AddResponse>();

        try {
            final AddResponse addResponse = addApi.add(request);
            addResponseWrapper.setResponse(addResponse);

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            addResponseWrapper.setErrorDetails(convert(e));
        }
        return addResponseWrapper;
    }

     public ResponseWrapper<Delete> delete(Request request)  {

     final ResponseWrapper<Delete> deleteResponseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper<Delete>();

        try {
            final DeleteResponse deleteResponse = deleteApi.delete(request);
            deleteResponseWrapper.setResponse(deleteResponse);

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            deleteResponseWrapper.setErrorDetails(convert(e));
        }
        return deleteResponseWrapper;
    }
}
```

Without changing the API class you can't go much further on simplification.